# spring boot how to load entity classes using @EntityScan and exclude some classes based on certain pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

the scenario here is like:

a simple java spring project where there're some entities in their own package, when i add the entity classes to the project i use

```
@EntityScan(basePackage="com.path.to.entities")
```

i want to exclude a certain @Entity or some of them based on a pattern i.e name or regEx and don't want it to be added

i've searched and found a similar implementation for @ComponentScan by using @Filter to include or exclude components, is there a similar approach for @EntityScan to do the same with entities?

Comment: No. There is no such filter attribute for entity scan. Recommended solution is to reorganize your package structure.

Answer (score 0):

by default spring picks every entities to be read, if you want specific package to be excluded, unfortunately there is no such attribute to exclude specific package, but alternatively you can use `@EntityScan(basePackages={YOUR_FIRST_PACKAGE,YOUR_SECOND_PACKAGE})`  so spring will only pick from those specified packages